# Google is returning 401 Unauthorized (NAT Router)

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine, http-status-code-401

When I try use f.e. google maps API, sometimes it is asking for login and password in the browser, and then it is returning 401 Unauthorized in the browser (Firefox 37).

Then when I try to go to the www.google.com and try to search something, it is doing the same thing - 401 Unauthorized.

What does this mean and why is it showing? After couple minutes it is gone (sometimes it is enough to clear cache of the browser).

Now I tried load www.google.com:

```
Connection  
close
Content-Type    
text/html
Date    
Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:02:23 GMT
Server  
httpd
WWW-Authenticate    
Basic realm="NAT Router"
```

**Auth:**

```
No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.

WWW-Authenticate Header is present: Basic realm="NAT Router"
```

The message in the dialog box of the browser (where login and password are asked) is "NAT Router".

Comment: "NAT router" login prompt suggests that you are running into issue within your local network (are you running local HTTP proxy?). Collect HTTP headers during one of those faulty sessions from your browser and add it to your question. You need to provide more information so people can help you.

Comment: @IlyaZakreuski No, we have no proxy in our office. I added HTTP headers.

Comment: f*ck you, downvoter... a human has some problems, and you rather downvote, instead of helping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid some networking equipment at your office intercepts HTTP sessions and acts as transparent HTTP proxy which requires authentication and prompts you for login/password. This could be just a misconfiguration, security feature or even malicious activity.

I would recommend you to investigate this in more detail with a networking specialist who knows the topology of your local network, etc. Additional information provided in the question is not enough to tell for sure.

Comment: Is it possible, that this is happening only for *.google.com websites and APIs?

Comment: @Legionar, yes, technically it is possible that authentication prompt appears only for a certain domain, while all other traffic flows normally. It is an open question why it might be happening and you need to inspect your network equipment configuration.